# How do I display a simple string array in a custom xamDataGrid field?

Tags: c#, xaml, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have this problem with xamDataGrid. It is working perfectly fine with a Dictionary datasource with two custom fields if I set their Names to Key and Value. 
So I set the datasource to the array (Binding to a Custom Property.SubProperty <- that is the string[]). I set up a custom FieldLayout (I need a custom label, that is why I need a custom field.). For my Field I require a "Name" property. But it does not have a Name. I tried "Value", I even tried Binding to Property and setting FieldLayout Key to Subproperty.
So the code looks somehow like this:

```
    <igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.Property.StringArraySubProperty}">
      //...FieldLayoutSettings...
      //...FieldSettings...
      <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        <igDP:FieldLayout>
          <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
            <igDP:Field Name="???Value???orWhat?"
                        Label="Stuff"/>
        <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
      </igDP:FieldLayout>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
  </igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

If I set it to AutoGeneratedFields, it is perfect. The values appear in a field with the label "Value". But anyhow, what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `TemplateField`

```
<igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
    <igDP:TemplateField >
        <igDP:TemplateField.DisplayTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </igDP:TemplateField.DisplayTemplate>
    </igDP:TemplateField>
</igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
```

Comment: Except TextBlock wouldn't have a Label property. Otherwise I'd agree.

Comment: @Hey.There Try adding PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High to the binding. See what you see in the debug pane. Are there empty rows, or really nothing at all?